# How to download a database of bibliographic information for all published scientific papers?

Tags: online-resource

I would like to download a database containing all scientific papers published. This is obviously too broad and ambitious. To be realistic, say I want all the papers searchable on google scholar (although other databases are fine, say SemanticScholar, etc.), or an approximation of that. What databases out there allow you to download this data?

I don't want to download the papers themselves (that wouldn't fit on my storage), just a record containing title, authors, journal (if it is not a book), year, and perhaps abstract.

Is this possible? How can I download a database like this, that I can browse and search offline?

Comment: No, it’s not possible.

Comment: Get a database admin job at Thomson Reuters?

Comment: @DanBron That's pessimistic. A way to do it is to wget google scholar searches with a single letter, a, b, c, ... A simple script could do it. I am just wondering if there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: At best that would get you all papers indexed by Google Scholar.  But Google Scholar is not an index of **all** scientific papers; at best, it's an index of scientific papers whose metadata is available online.  (Similarly, not all scientific papers are indexed by Thomson Reuters, or even by the union of Google Scholar and Thomson Reuters.)

Comment: @JeffE I should have been more specific in my question. But an index containing all of Google Scholar or an approximation of it, is more than sufficient for me.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the *closest* you can get is the [Open Academic Graph](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/open-academic-graph/), a graph-based database of about 321 *million* papers (I don't think the actual papers are stored, but all the information you want is there). You can download all the 143 GB of data from the above link, but do note that because it's a merge of two existing graph-based paper databases ([Microsoft Academic Search](https://academic.microsoft.com/) and [AMiner](https://aminer.org/)) there are going to be *a lot* of duplicates.

Comment: Thanks (+1). Do you know if the data from Microsoft Academic Search can be downloaded by itself?

Comment: @becko Yes, the downloads in the link separate the data of both databases. You'd want just the MAS ones in that case.

Answer (score 6):

You can download a number of databases, but none, as far as I know, are comprehensive across all fields.

- [CiteSeerX data](http://csxstatic.ist.psu.edu/about/data) is available by request.
- [PubMed data](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/databases/download/pubmed_medline.html)
- [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data), which contains some publication information

You might also want to check the [list of repositories](https://www.openarchives.org/Register/BrowseSites) compliant with the OAI-PMH metadata harvesting protocol.